# 2D lighting with shaders - light radius affected by window size

Tags: opengl, 2d, glsl, shader, lighting

I have a shader which adds lighting to an otherwise 2D scene (lights are slightly above the 2D plane).  In my fragment shader, I loop through each light to calculate the direction and distance by applying my ortho matrix to the light's pos.

The problem is, the light's "radius" is affected by the size and aspect ratio of my window.  I thought that translating the coordinates using the ortho matrix would ensure that the screen size wouldn't matter, but a wide window produces an oval light, and smaller windows produce smaller ovals than larger windows.  Should I be using another matrix of some sort?

Full shader here (change window size to see the unwanted effect): http://glsl.heroku.com/e#14464.0

```
uniform vec2 resolution;

void main(void)
{
    //orthographic matrix
    mat4 ortho_matrix = mat4(
        2.0/resolution.x, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 2.0/-resolution.y, 0, 0,
        0, 0, -1, 0,
        -1, 1, 0, 1
        );

    //surface normal of the 2D plane (looking straight down)
    vec3 surface_normal = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    //screen position of the light
    vec2 light_screen_pos = vec2(650, 150);

    //translate light's position to normalized coordinates
    //the z value makes sure it is slightly above the 2D plane
    vec4 light_ortho_pos = ortho_matrix * vec4(light_screen_pos, -0.03, 1.0);

    //calculate the light for this fragment
    vec3 light_direction = light_ortho_pos.xyz - vec3(gl_FragCoord.x / resolution.x, gl_FragCoord.y / resolution.y, 0);
    float dist = length(light_direction);
    light_direction = normalize(light_direction);
    vec3 light = clamp(dot(surface_normal, light_direction), 0.0, 1.0) * vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    vec3 cel_light = step(0.15, (light.r + light.g + light.b) / 3.0) * light;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(pow(light + cel_light, vec3(0.4545)), 1.0);
}
```

Note: I know it's not optimal to make this calculation for each light, each pixel - I should be passing the light's position in another uniform probably.

Comment: I'm not sure why "normal" involves a texture. Can you explain what pixcoord is or simplify this a bit? Only one light is needed to figure out the problem, right? And since this is all about current_light and it really only depends on light_direction and normal, you can probably remove attenuation from that line and see what happens.

Comment: I tried to edit it down a bit...the sprites have a base texture and a texture with a normal map which is used by the frag shader.  Pixcoord is just the position from the vertex shader after the ortho matrix is applied.  I use the ortho matrix to translate exact screen pixel coordinates.

Comment: Thanks. Do you apply the same ortho_matrix to gl_Position to get pixcoord? It seems to me that that would be better done in the fragment shader. What happens if you remove cel_light altogether? If the problem still remains, then we'll be getting somewhere. I'm not sure what your aim is with `mix(vec3(-1), vec3(1), normal)`, can you explain?

Comment: I do use the same ortho matrix in the vertex shader.  I further simplified it and posted a link to a WebGL version with editable code for easy experimentation.  The mix() function was translating the normal map colors from the normals texture to a normalized range (i.e. -1 to 1 rather than 0 to 1).  I've removed it and just hardcoded the values for clarity.

Comment: I tried to put `light_screen_pos` in the middle of the view by writing it in terms of `resolution`, for instance: `light_screen_pos = vec2(0.5*resolution.x, 0.5*resolution.y)`, but I got weird results. I would play around with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The light direction needs to be scaled according to screen resolution.  I ended up adding the following code to make it work, with an arbitrary brightness of 500 or so:

```
light_direction *= vec3(resolution.x / brightness, resolution.y / brightness, 1.0);
```

Comment: The ortho matrix puts the light in the correct location on the screen, but the shape of the light (its apparent "radius") was not affected until I scaled the direction calculation as well.